# How to explain light beams in terms of wave theory?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, radiation, laser

How can we explain the formation of light beams in terms of wave theory?

According to wave theory, shouldn't the source point of beams emit radiation omnidirectionally, rather than a concentrated slender straight line of light (or radiation)?

[image: DOUBLE SLIT EXPERIMENT]
[image: LASER BEAM]

Comment: Google Gaussian optics.

Comment: I was not thinking about an explicit *point* when I used that word, though. But still the question is bugging me. Why do we draw *rays* of light starting from a point? How can a point emit rays rather than omnidirectional waves?

Comment: Or even here in the 2nd picture, the whole aperture is a collection of *point sources* (if it is okey to consider so), then how can a beam shoot out of an aperture? Rather than creating an interference pattern?

Comment: A point would emit waves omnidirectional waves. But, as the other comments mentioned, the output aperture of a laser is usually not designed to be a point.

Comment: @Photon, Well, that image is for illustration purposes only. I'm feeling that it's not relevant to enter into the bits and bytes of laser aperture. It should not be hard to imagine an idealized ***slender straight line of light***, as I've stated in the question. Can we explain this in terms of wave theory of light?

Comment: As I'm going through different articles (such as *Young's double slit experiment*), the question is evolving in my mind. I think an insight into a few questions might help me. Such as, *What does a point source emit?* Wave or Ray?, *Can flat wave fronts* emitting from a plane help to *explain light beams*?